# Generate objects from date range with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I got the following python class:

```
class CalendarMonth(Base, ...):
    __tablename__ = 'calendar_month'

    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    month = Column(String(50))
    ...
```

I filled the database with all the months (Januari, etc..). So I have 12 rows in total in the database.

What i want now is to have `list` function, which returns the months for every year. So basically just add a year column. And generates this infinite starting from the current date.

How do i do this?

I'm using a Postgresql database and the sqlalchemy ORM.

Comment: How about `generate_series(date_trunc('month', current_date), '3000-01-01', '1 month'::interval)`, then converted to a suitable representation.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work!

Comment: In that case you could write an answer to your own question here. It's perfectly ok to do so.